# Editing of rptdesign files (BIRT) in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, birt

Is there a way to edit rtpdesign-files (used by the BIRT-library) in IntelliJ? Currently, I have to switch between IntelliJ and Eclipse to do the editing.

Answer (score 2):

The graphical editor for `rptdesign` files is only available for Eclipse. Actuate distribute BIRT through the Eclipse Foundation so I think it's extremely unlikely that they will support other IDEs.

Answer (score 1):

Birt works as a Eclipse Plugin but you can allways use the standalone Birt designer.

[Birt Stand Alone Designer](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/about/designer.php)